# How put a caption in flv converted by ffmpeg

Tags: video, flash, ffmpeg, flv

I want to make such `flv` like in this **[video example](http://jp.fotolia.com/id/18064998)**

How do I do this?

Environment:

- Fedora release 8 (Werewolf)
- FFmpeg version SVN-r20412

Answer (score 2):

Before you convert it
...for that same effect as in the link.  Some other captioning is possible with Flex/Flash with existing videos--this would be done in the player.  [Example instructions](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/captions_flash_video/)

To overlay an image with **[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)**, could use ffmpeg's virtual hook (vhook) functionality.  (Although mature, it is apparently deprecated in the latest ffmpeg 0.5)  But the video you have there has lots of alpha blending going on, and to do that you'll want to read up on this blog post:  [Alpha blended watermarks with FFmpeg](http://refractalize.blogspot.com/2009/09/alpha-blended-watermarks-with-ffmpeg.html).  This approach requires a non-trivial effort.

Just about any video editing software has the capability to add captions.  Some even let you create your own.  The skies the limit.